# Multitab ViewPager with single Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an app which is using a `ViewPager` with about 20 tabs (actually this number will be a variable). The Fragment for all of these tabs has the same layout. So, what is the better way to reuse this fragment (in other words, to reinflate the fragment's view in accordance with a number of a tab)? 
Thank you!

Comment: You don't reuse instances of the fragment. The same fragment class can be used for several tabs, but each tab will be its own instances. See: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DesignSupport/TabLayout

Comment: Was your problem solved bro?

Comment: Sorry for absence - I had to distract to another problem. Vucko, yes today I've managed to solve this one! Thanks to everybody for the help! Now I only need to save some data for each fragment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not reuse the fragment instance. What you should reuse is the class itself (code reuse). So you will have a single fragment class; from which a separate instance needs to be created for each tab.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on something similar, I have 5 to 7 same fragments. Initialize them with a `private int orderNumber;` or something (if each has some specific data, also save that data. I'm using `List<DataSpecificClass>` but feel free to customize this whichever way you want.

It is also recommended to use [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) instead of the regular FragmentPagerAdapter.